# CORS Error: Unable to Upload Image from Cloudflare-Hosted Client Site to Heroku Server

Tags: node.js, heroku, cors, cloudflare

I have been stuck on this problem for about a month and I seriously am so lost. I have watched every YouTube video, every tutorial, and yet the problems prevail.

My intent is to upload an image from the client site (which is hosted on CloudFlare) to a Heroku server. That's it. Now, this works just fine when I host the site locally but when I make the call from CloudFlare where the site is hosted at "https://mysite.pages.dev" I get the error:
[image: The console error on the client site]
(from origin is actually 'https:', ignore the 'http:')

This is the code for my CorsOptions on the Heroku server

```
const cors = require("cors");
const corsOptions = {
    origin: "https://mysite.pages.dev",
    credentials: true,
    optionSuccessStatus: 200,
};
app.use(cors(corsOptions))

app.use("/test", require("./routes/test"));
```

And this is the code from the client website that makes the request (trust me I have 100x checked that the URL is the exact same I am just replacing the name with x's)

```
axios({
    headers: { "Content-Type": "multipart/form-data" },
    method: "post",
    url: "https://xxx.herokuapp.com/test",
    data: formData,
    withCredentials: true,
})
```

Btw these are the logs from the Heroku server, if they help 
[image]

I tried allowing all origins like so

```
app.use(cors())
```

But that just produces the same error

Comment: `https://mysite.pages.dev` != `http://mysite.pages.dev`

Comment: Yes I was using a screenshot from a different link, I made a comment saying it is infact https not http, I just had the incorrect screenshot.

Answer (score 1):

No shot I finally found the problem.

TLDR; My folder that holds the uploads in the Heroku server was not getting tracked by Git because it is empty. Add ".gitkeep" file in an empty folder

So the reason for the 503 error and no origin error even though I have the origins defined is because when I make the request to upload the file it attempts to upload to an "upload" folder but it doesn't exist so the app crashed (503 error meaning process interrupted)

The solution was to add a file to the empty folder so that when I push to Git it doesn't ignore it for being empty. I made a ".gitkeep" file in my empty "uploads" folder and this solved all the issues. I'm only keeping this up for that one person probably in 7 years who will run into this same exact scenario.